# Hapi Server Crashes upon Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi

I am making trying to take a backend using Hapi for the first time but every time a request is sent to the server it crashes. Sometimes I do get a response but the server eventually crashes on its own.

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'statusCode')
    at Request._finalize (C:\Users\prakh\Desktop\Angular\buy-and-sell-backend\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:491:31)
    at Request._reply (C:\Users\prakh\Desktop\Angular\buy-and-sell-backend\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:428:18)
    at Request._execute (C:\Users\prakh\Desktop\Angular\buy-and-sell-backend\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:274:14)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

The code is simple since I am only testing right now:

```
import Hapi from '@hapi/hapi'

const start = async () => {
    const server = Hapi.server({
        port: 8000,
        host: 'localhost',
    });

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/hello',
        handler: (req, h) => {
            return 'Hello!';
        }
    });
    
    await server.start();
    console.log(`Server is listening on ${server.info.uri}`)
}

process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
});

start();
```

I am using Node v16.17.0 and the command I use to run it is npx babel-node src/server.js

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/4319

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix.

Had to update the Hapi version that I was using.

Use: npm uninstall @hapi/hapi
and then: npm install @hapi/hapi

Hapi 20.2.2 works